# A question about a semigroup with two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, idempotents, finite-semigroups

Let $(\{p,q\},∗)$ be a semigroup, where $p∗p=q$. I want to show that:

$$q∗q=q$$

I know semigroups are closed and associative, but I am not able to prove this equality.

Comment: @Teddy38, your forgot to put backslashes in front of the OP's curly braces. (I can't fix this because it's only a two-character edit.)

Comment: @PersonX Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Suppose to the contrary that $q*q=p$.

Case 1: $p*q=p$.  Try to derive a contradiction thinking about $p*p*q$.

Case 2: $p*q=q$.  Same advice as case 1.

Comment: yes you are right. I did not think that way.Thanks